# Connect php with Android, security methods

Tags: php, android, api

I'm sending data from an Android app to a php script which recieves the information and procces it, I've found a security issue: if someone discovered the url (for example: mydomain.com/recievedata.php), anyone would be able to send data to my system.

What's the ideal method to ensure the client sending the data is the app?

Thanks!

Comment: May be add special content in request header? This still can be cracked, but not by just looking at url.

Comment: Special content like what? I mean is there any specification or something? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One easy way that I've seen some companies do is to include a secret key. For example, you might have a `secret=3CH6knCsYmvA2va8GrHk4mf3JqmUctCM` parameter to your POST data. Then all you need at the top of `receivedata.php` is

```
if($_POST['secret'] != '3CH6knCsYmvA2va8GrHk4mf3JqmUctCM') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    error_log("ERROR: wrong secret: " . $_POST['secret']);
    exit("Access denied");
}
```

You can easily generate the random string from [random.org](https://www.random.org/strings/).

Of course, this is not the most secure method and that string might well be stored in plaintext in the APK (don't use this to send launch codes!), but it's easy and good enough to keep most people out. This might be adequate for, say, sending player scores for a game.

Comment: Hi, this is how I did the code but they said to me that it's not secure enough to send data like user_id in the registration and other stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea what else they want? Do they want users to log in? Do they need the data being passed to be encrypted? These are different types of concerns.

Answer (score 3):

It's more like a PHP question. Here are the things you should do for security ;

- Add a hash between your app and your PHP to sync (AKA secret key)
- Make sure your script controls every input data
- DO NOT send datas to query without escaping them (SQL Inject)
- Try to use POST instead of GET or REQUEST
- Keep your functions private as much as possible
- Always parse the data you receieve (Check if its a number, or string or array etc)

With these, noone will be able to use any of your PHP files without your app. And they won't be able to receive any data without your permissions

Answer (score 1):

The only proper way is not trusting the data you receive. Always treat it in a way suitable for crafted data coming from a bad guy.